# fixed and center navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to make a fixed and center navbar with a display width of 70%. When I change the position to fixed, it always moves to the left size.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar,
main {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background: #1a1c1b;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo-box">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">MOVIES</a>
    </div>

    <div class="search-box">
      <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
        <input id="seach-bar" name="q" type="search" placeholder="Search MOVIES" autocomplete="off">
        <button id="search-button" type="submit" class="search">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Genres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Celebs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">My List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks guys it worked. However the background color of my navbar is also limited to 70%. Can i make only the content 70%? Just like other websites, for example this stackoverflow navbar

Comment: if one of these answers worked for you, accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside the answer. I recommend you to upvote the answer as well to further show your appreciation. If you have further questions, you should either create a new question or comment on the relevant answer.

Comment: Why have you declared styles for main if it's not being used in the above code? And why's the style for navbar written twice?

Comment: I didnt write the content for main yet. My idea is to set the navbar and main content to only 70% of the page. And other properties such as fixed position and padding I only want for navbar not main, hence the repeat of navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left` and `transform` property to center your navbar as you are using `position: fixed;` on your navbar.

```css
/* some resets */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar,
main {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background: #1a1c1b;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* centering your navbar */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo-box">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">MOVIES</a>
    </div>

    <div class="search-box">
      <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
        <input id="seach-bar" name="q" type="search" placeholder="Search MOVIES" autocomplete="off">
        <button id="search-button" type="submit" class="search">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Genres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Celebs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">My List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**SECOND Method** : you can wrap your navbar in a container and apply `flexbox` or `grid`.

I used flexbox *as you already wrapped your navbar inside the header*.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* centring your navbar */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar,
main {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background: #1a1c1b;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo-box">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">MOVIES</a>
    </div>

    <div class="search-box">
      <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
        <input id="seach-bar" name="q" type="search" placeholder="Search MOVIES" autocomplete="off">
        <button id="search-button" type="submit" class="search">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Genres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Celebs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">My List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**The fixed you asked**

```js
document.querySelector('header').style.height = document.querySelector('.navbar').getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* centring your navbar */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* set it black */
  background-color: #1a1c1b;
}

.navbar {
  width: 70%;
  position: fixed;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo-box">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">MOVIES</a>
    </div>

    <div class="search-box">
      <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
        <input id="seach-bar" name="q" type="search" placeholder="Search MOVIES" autocomplete="off">
        <button id="search-button" type="submit" class="search">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Genres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Celebs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">My List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**Without JavaScript and easier method!**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar .container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1125px;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .container .logo {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .container .search,
.navbar .container form {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .container .search input[type=search],
.navbar .container form input[type=search] {
  color: white;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar .container .search input[type=search]::-moz-placeholder,
.navbar .container form input[type=search]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar .container .search input[type=search]:-ms-input-placeholder,
.navbar .container form input[type=search]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar .container .search input[type=search]::placeholder,
.navbar .container form input[type=search]::placeholder {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar .container .search button[type=submit],
.navbar .container form button[type=submit] {
  width: 37.2px;
  display: grid;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 37.2px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar .container .search button[type=submit] svg,
.navbar .container form button[type=submit] svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.navbar .container .navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar .container .navbar-nav .nav-item:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 3rem;
}

.navbar .container .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .container .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Movies</a>

    <div class="search">
      <form action="#">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" required />
        <button type="submit">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path d="M10 18a7.952 7.952 0 0 0 4.897-1.688l4.396 4.396 1.414-1.414-4.396-4.396A7.952 7.952 0 0 0 18 10c0-4.411-3.589-8-8-8s-8 3.589-8 8 3.589 8 8 8zm0-14c3.309 0 6 2.691 6 6s-2.691 6-6 6-6-2.691-6-6 2.691-6 6-6z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Genres</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Celebs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">My List</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I used the flexbox method and it worked. Can i make the backbround color of my header is still 100% and only the navbar content is 70%?

Comment: Sorry! I don't quite understand your question! 

Comment: you can run the code from your reply and see that the black color from my header is also limited to 70% but i want it to cover the full length of the page.

Comment: then increase the length of your `.navbar` to `100%` or you can set `background-color: transparent;` of navbar and set `background-color: black` of header.

Comment: There is one more better way to achieve what you wanted on the first place. Let me know if you want to learn.

Comment: actually i want my content (text, logo) of the <header> and <main> to stay 70% in the center of the page. but the background color of the header to cover 100%. As you can look at the navbar of this stackoverflow website.

Comment: sorry just saw your comment about the js code. is there a way to do this without js?

Comment: yes there are several ways wait I am sending you the link for that!

Comment: I updated the code above you can check and see that on full page view. You can change the color as you want of your navbar.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use flexbox!

Make the header as a **flexbox** with `justify-content` property to **center align** the navigation bar on the **horizontal axis**.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The background color of my navbar is also limited to 70%. Can i make only the content 70%? Just like other websites, for example this stackoverflow navbar

Answer (score 0):

```
     body {
      background-color: black;
     }

     .navbar{
       width: 70%;
       margin-left: 15%;
       margin-right: auto;
       position: fixed;
       background: #1a1c1b;
       padding: 5px 0;
      }
```

This should work for you, the problem seems to be that you applied the 70% width to both the body and the nav, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class, for example "header" and assigning it the following properties:

```
.header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
background: #1a1c1b;
```

and then you place your navbar.

```
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
        </nav>
    </header>
```